# How to RTL this android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I want to rtl (Right To Left) below layout in android like when using `layoutDirection="rtl"` in parent layout (but it only for 4.2 and higher) and any way to make it direction to right-to-left clearly.
This is a part of main android project layout which used for Preference Activity in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
Layout for a Preference in a PreferenceActivity. The
Preference is able to place a specific widget for its particular
type in the "widget_frame" layout.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Sorry for my weak English!!)

Comment: Did you try simply adding `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to the top-level `<LinearLayout>` tag?

Comment: I add this before and every thing is good, but it's only for android 4.2 and higher, and my min sdk version is 8

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, RTL layout support feature is supported on Android 4.2(API level 17) or above only. For the versions before, you can add a layout folder for RTL layout. For example in `layout` folder you put LTR version files layout and in `layout-ldrtl` folder you put RTL version files layout.

As of what to change to make RTL it depends on how much you would like to make it in RTL. because some parts of view will remain on the same side (like navigation bar) unless you customize it. Other things you will have to see and change what should be changed to make it cool view. For example on the LTR view lets say we have this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then on the RTL view you will be somethig like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see we have changed the padding in the `android:paddingLeft="4dp"` and `android:paddingRight="8dp"` but we kept the `android:layout_gravity="left"` because it should be like that for this case (maybe on another view will be `android:layout_gravity="right"`).

As real life example, you can compare the two views of the Android Quran app [RTL audio_panel](https://github.com/quran/quran_android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout-ar/audio_panel.xml) and [LTR audio_panel](https://github.com/quran/quran_android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/audio_panel.xml).

Comment: Thank you, I know this, but my question is how to rtl a layout with xml attributes like gravity and etc.

Comment: The question was not clear to that point. I've edited the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in root layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
```

Comment: I asked this question in 2014, but thank you!